# can't remove gnome-shell and gnome-shell-extensions

Tags: apt

The problem is that I can't remove the **gnome-shell** and **gnome-shell-extensions**. When I try to delete with Ubuntu Software Center there is an error:

Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Details:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme:

And when I try to delete with terminal:

araqkh@araqkh-U30Jc:~$ sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-extensions
[sudo] password for araqkh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
araqkh@araqkh-U30Jc:~$
```

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 TLS

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Im having exactly the same issue as you

Comment: have you tried to install that package: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme` ?

Comment: It returns this error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: have you tried to install that package: sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme ? – shinnra

Ofcourse I tryed. Absolutely the same error.
Well it is not a problem to reinstall Ubuntu but anyway... I'd like to understand what's the deal

Answer (score 0):

gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme was never in the official Ubuntu repositories. Be careful when using software from PPAs.

Have you tried removing gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme. Maybe remove gnome-shell*.